# Validate PDF Document

Tags: aspose, aspose.pdf

I'm just wondering if there's a way to check if the pdf file is valid or if it does not contain any errors. Currently, what we have is just this code to check if the file is valid.

```
var pdfDocument = new Document(stream)
```

where the stream is the MemoryStream of the document. However, when I tried to upload a pdf file and add an image to it, I get an error (cross reference thingy). I checked online if this PDF is valid and I got this error message.

[image]

I want something or some code to catch the error. I have an idea on how, but I need your expert suggestion on how to do this.

Comment: Aspose.Pdf for .NET provides Document.Validate() method to validate the compliance of PDF-A format. You simply need to pass path of log.xml file and format type to the method like following:

Document pdfDocument = new Document("ValidatePDFAStandard.pdf");
// Validate PDF for PDF/A-1a
pdfDocument.Validate("validation-result-A1A.xml", PdfFormat.PDF_A_1A);

The XML log contains a collection of tags with the name Problem; each tag contains the details of a particular problem. I work as support developer at Aspose.

Comment: Is it possible to not pass in the xml file but throw the comments in a string? The reason is that we have a log file and I want to log all the comments there.

Comment: When using above mentioned approach of Validate(..) method, you can specify the exact PDF/A compliance format which you need to verify and you can also save the compliance validation output in file or in Stream instance. 
Apart from this approach, you may consider using following property to determine if the input file is PDF/A compliant or not.

Document doc = new Document(@"C:\pdftest\input.pdf");
// determine if the input file is PDF/A compliant
Console.WriteLine(doc.IsPdfaCompliant);

Comment: @codewarior So in short, there is no way for me to get the comments via a return string? Because what I intend to do is something like this `string comments = pdfDocument.Validate(...); logger.Debug(comments);` Something like that

Comment: @Musikero31
As shared above, if you need to get the content of validation method, you can save the output in Stream instance or in some separate log file on file system and then add that content to logger. In order to save the contents of Validation method to file, please try using the approach shared above by Asad.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
// Open document
Document pdfDocument = new Document(dataDir + "ValidatePDFAStandard.pdf");
    
// Validate PDF for PDF/A-1a

bool validation = pdfDocument.Validate(dataDir + "validation-result-A1A.xml", PdfFormat.PDF_A_1A);
if(!validation)
{
   // invalid

}
```

see also:
https://docs.aspose.com/pdf/net/manipulate-pdf-document/